# Uncaught TypeError: ymaps.GeoObjectCollection is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Вроде код использую такой же, как в документации Яндекса, но в консоле стабильно ошибка:
`Uncaught TypeError: ymaps.GeoObjectCollection is not a constructor`

script.js:

```
// Функция ymaps.ready() будет вызвана, когда
// загрузятся все компоненты API, а также когда будет готово DOM-дерево.
ymaps.ready(init);

var myMap,
    myPlacemark;

function init(){
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 7
    });

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64],{
        hintContent: 'Я здесь!'
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}

//кластеры
var coords = [
    [56.023, 36.988],
    [56.025, 36.981],
    [56.020, 36.981],
    [56.021, 36.983],
    [56.027, 36.987]
];

var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();

for (var i = 0; i<coords.length; i++) {
    myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords[i]));
}

myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключите скрипт с API Yandex Maps в index.html.
Зачастую ошибка заключена именно в этом.

Стоит так же учитывать, что для подключения необходим токен, получить который можно в кабинете разработчика, где Вы и подключаете API Yandex.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос